# Query performance on DefaultIfEmpty with null property

Tags: c#, performance, linq, linq-to-sql, entity-framework-core

i wrote a query to fetch data like this

```
public class NewsResModel
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
}

IQueryable<NewsResModel> query = FindByCondition(
            o.Title.Contains(qModel.Titel ?? String.Empty))
            .Select(x => new NewsResModel {
                Title = x.Title
            }).AsNoTracking();
```

and in a generic class i called query:

```
List<T> items = await query.DefaultIfEmpty().ToListAsync();
```

is it better remove `DefaultIfEmpty` and make query like this:

```
.Select(x => new NewsResModel {
                Title = x.Title ?? ""
            })
```

i have more null string propery in `NewsResModel` also some other class will using this generic method to return  `item< T >`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well first what is your definition time in performance? seconds? miliseconds?

configuring dbcontext by disabling lazy loading or tracking sure does some trick in performance

however if you really want to speed up the queries I would suggest rather then returning all the fields of a a class return only the ones you will be using.

**DefaultIfEmpty() is Equivalent to LEFT JOIN in a SQL query**

so the question to be asked is : How would changing a JOIN to LEFT JOIN affect the performance of the query? will there be a change in performance? yes, will it be too much ? depending on the number of rows yes. 
therefore use it only if you really **need that data!**

Comment: if i dont use DefaultIfEmpty or not using Title = x.Title ?? "" , when i fetch query to list it'll return error as data can not be null

Comment: are you using code first? if so

the forein keys u can add as nullable for example:

public int? parentRefNo {get;set;}

Comment: Title property is string and by default is null, and when i try to use it in generic method i got null refrence error. i found a solution in c#8 nullable, maybe it can help me

Comment: strings by default are nullable, you can set a string to null but you can't set an int value to null unless you define it as nullable int which is done -> int? propName;
the question mark on int tells that it's nullable alternatively you can use it as public Nullable<int> test { get; set; }